# Convert python functions (shortestpath/ prediction function using nx.adamic_adar_index) into API

Tags: python, graph, graph-algorithm, prediction, shortest-path

So in this project im trying to find the link prediction in the social networks.

I have done my test with some of the algorithms, and I decided to work with the Adamic radar algorithm.

And I wanted to do an HTML interface to get the prediction in.

so I dunno how to convert the python function into APIs, I tried with fastApi but nothing happened.

Can you please help me?

So here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import networkx as nx
from tqdm import tqdm
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import auc
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score


# load nodes details
with open("/content/drive/MyDrive/fb-pages-food.nodes") as f:
    fb_nodes = f.read().splitlines() 

# load edges (or links)
with open("/content/drive/MyDrive/fb-pages-food.edges") as f:
    fb_links = f.read().splitlines() 

len(fb_nodes), len(fb_links)


# capture nodes in 2 separate lists
node_list_1 = []
node_list_2 = []

for i in tqdm(fb_links):
  node_list_1.append(i.split(',')[0])
  node_list_2.append(i.split(',')[1])

fb_df = pd.DataFrame({'node_1': node_list_1, 'node_2': node_list_2})


# create graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(fb_df, "node_1", "node_2")

# plot graph
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

pos = nx.random_layout(G, seed=23)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True,  pos = pos, node_size = 280, alpha = 0.6, width = 1)

from networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted import dijkstra_path
def dijkstrapath(source,target):
  print('Returns the shortest path from source to target in a weighted graph G')
  if (source and target) in G:
    x = dijkstra_path(G , source= source, target= target, weight="weight")
    print(x)
  # else:
  #   print('nodes are not in the graph')
  
dij = dijkstrapath('0','54')
dij


# Remove 20% of the edges
proportion_edges = 0.2
edge_subset = random.sample(G.edges(), int(proportion_edges * G.number_of_edges()))

# Create a copy of the graph and remove the edges
G_train = G.copy()
G_train.remove_edges_from(edge_subset)

# Prediction using Adamic Adar 
pred_adamic = list(nx.adamic_adar_index(G_train))
score_adamic, label_adamic = zip(*[(s, (u,v) in edge_subset) for (u,v,s) in pred_adamic])
pred_adamic*100
```

** so this is the function that I want to use in my HTML so I guess I need it as an API. HOW TO DO THIS . **

**BUT IF OF COURSE THERE IS ANOTHER IDEA PLEASE TELL ME, I AM A BEGINNER **

```
# Prediction using Adamic Adar 
def prediction__(u,v):
  if u in G and v in G:
    preds = nx.adamic_adar_index(G, [(u, v)])
    for u, v, p in preds:
      print('(%d, %d) -> %.8f' % (u, v, p))
  else:
    print('nodes not found')
```

this what I have done in fastAPI but nothing works of course because it's wrong

```
from fastapi import FastAPI , Response, status
from colabcode import ColabCode
from pydantic import BaseModel

# Modeling

app = FastAPI(title="Link Prediction",
              description="Prediction Model of Future Connections between Facebook Pages", 
              version="1.0")

app = FastAPI()


# class allNodes(BaseModel):
#     node1: int
#     node2 : int


# prediction = {}

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

# @app.get("/prediction")
# async def get_prediction(Node1, Node2) -> allNodes:
#   if Node1 and Node2 in G:
#     preds = nx.adamic_adar_index(G, Node1, Node2)
#     for Node1, Node2, p in preds:
#       print('(%d, %d) -> %.8f' % (Node1, Node2, p))

@app.get("/shortPath")
def dijkstrapath(source,target):
  if (source and target) in G:
    x = dijkstra_path(G , source= source, target= target, weight="weight")
  return x
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE FOR YOUR HELP